# Search Github user

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to find a github user using Axios, but I am receiving the following error :

> Error: "Request failed with status code 404"
>           exports https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js:2
>           exports https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js:2
>           onreadystatechange https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js:2
>       2.html:44:25

This is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UFT-8">
  <title> </title>
</head>
<body>

  <form id="form-usuario" onsubmit="searchUsuario()" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user" id="usuario" placeholder="Informe o usuario do github">
    <button type="submit">Adicionar</button>
  </form>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    //função para procurar o usuário
    function searchUsuario() {
      alert("searching...")
      event.preventDefault()

      let coleta = document.getElementById("usuario").value

      axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/${coleta}/repos')
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Replace the quotes around `'http...repos'` with backticks ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to add some var into strigs you need to use that kind of 
quotation marks: ``, the backticks.

Try change `` instead '' on `axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/${coleta}/repos')`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UFT-8">
  <title> </title>
</head>
<body>

  <form id="form-usuario" onsubmit="searchUsuario()" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user" id="usuario" placeholder="Informe o usuario do github">
    <button type="submit">Adicionar</button>
  </form>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    //função para procurar o usuário
    function searchUsuario() {
      alert("searching...")
      event.preventDefault()

      let coleta = document.getElementById("usuario").value

      axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${coleta}/repos`)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```